# How to get the Save State after App is Restarted?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-togglebutton

> I am trying to Implement a toggle button (Favorite) in the RecyclerView adapter
>
> As i click on the ToggleButton, it is successfully favorited and clicking again unfavorites as well, BUT the problem is how can I save this state locally even after app is restarted.
>
> Here is my Model Class :

```
 int toggled = R.drawable.ic_star_red_24dp;
    int untoglled = R.drawable.ic_star_border_black_24dp;
    boolean isFavorite = false;
public int getToggled() {
        return toggled;
    }

    public int getUntoglled() {
        return untoglled;
    }


    public void setFavorite(boolean favorite) {
        isFavorite = favorite;
    }

    public boolean isFavorite() {
        return isFavorite;
    }
```

> Here is my Adapter code for OnClick() of toggle Button :

```
holder.favorite.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (newsModel.isFavorite)
                newsModel.setFavorite(false);
            else
                newsModel.setFavorite(true);
            notifyItemChanged(position);
        }
    });
```

> ALso this :

```
  if (newsModel.isFavorite())
        holder.favorite.setBackgroundResource(newsModel.getToggled());
    else
        holder.favorite.setBackgroundResource(newsModel.getUntoglled());
```

> Now, How do i save the state ?

Comment: You can save the value in any local database like SQLite or Room and retrieve it when app restarted.

Comment: How can I do that ? Please provide some codes

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to persist the model data by either of the following ways:

1. [Room Persistence Library](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/room)
2. [Realm for Android](https://realm.io/blog/realm-for-android/)
3. [SQLite](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/sqlite)

Comment: There are many tutorials available on Google. The links which I've shared also provides code snippets.